# Action Button Not Showing Drawable in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to get an action button to appear in my action bar, however I am only able to get the action overflow to show up instead of the drawable. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B19UQbxamvCiMEpTTVFwUVpIZlk/view?usp=sharing) is what I see.

Here is my menu_friends.xml source:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:binder="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- action_friends should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_friends"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_plus_grey600_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_edit_friends_label"
        binder:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```

Here is the fragment where I am inflating the menu:

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_friends, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_friends:
            navigateToEditFriends();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
    private void navigateToEditFriends() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(FriendsFragment.this.getActivity(), EditFriendsActivity.class);
       startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mDrawerItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_titles);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // set a custom shadow that overlays the menu_main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,  GravityCompat.START);
        // Add items to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerItems));
        // Set the OnItemClickListener so something happens when a
        // user clicks on an item.
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle the NavigationDrawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

/*        // Set the default content area to item 0
        // when the app opens for the first time
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {

        }*/


        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            navigateTo(position);
        }
    }
    private void navigateTo(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
navigateToSettings();
                break;
            case 1:
userLogout();
                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }



    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return (position ==0)? "Inbox" : "Friends";
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return (position ==0)? new InboxFragment() : new FriendsFragment();
         }
     }

    private void userLogout() {
        ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private void navigateToSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!
-R

Answer (score 1):

Put the setHasOptionsMenu() in your Fragments onCreate methode and not in onCreateView() methode. That should do the trick.

Comment: Remove that menu.clear(). I belive thats not nessesary. Your code looks very simmliar to mine so this should actually work. For an closer view in your code i have to use my Computer which is actually not here.